# Using Fractional Distance as Distance Metric for K Means Clustering for High Dimensional Dataset in Python

Tags: python, scikit-learn, k-means

I have datasets of at least 30 features to be clustered via k means clustering on Python. Does anyone has any idea on how can I set fractional distance (https://medium.com/@amit02093/the-right-distance-approximation-in-high-dimensions-fractional-distances-bb0b8cd858b2) as the distance metric for K mean clustering? SK learn seem not to have fractional distance. Thank you in advance!

This is the code for fractional distance which I have obtained from another stackoverflow post:

```
def fractional_distance(p_coord_array, q_coord_array):
  # f is an arbitrary value, but must be greater than zero and 
  # less than one. In this case, I used 3/10. I took advantage
  # of the difference of cubes in this case, so that I wouldn't
  # encounter an overflow error.

    a = np.sum(np.array(p_coord_array, dtype=np.float64))
    b = np.sum(np.array(q_coord_array, dtype=np.float64))
    a2 = np.sum(np.power(p_coord_array, 2))
    ab = np.sum(p_coord_array) * np.sum(q_coord_array)
    b2 = np.sum(np.power(p_coord_array, 2))
    diffab = a - b
    suma2abb2 = a2 + ab + b2

    temp_dist = abs(diffab * suma2abb2)
    temp_dist = np.power(temp_dist, 1./10)

    dist = np.power(temp_dist, 10./3)
    return dist
```